# Bar chart of grades using asterisks

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to make a program that asks the user how many grades they want to enter. Then, after they enter the grades a horizontal bar chart is printed of how many of the grades fall between a certain range using asterisks(range is 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, etc. to 100). Right now, my code takes the user input, stores the entered grades and prints the values that fall between  the specified range but does so incorrectly (i.e. if two grades fall between 80-89 it will print 80-89:* then 80-89:* below it as oppose to 80-89:**). Lastly, I can't figure out an easier way to do this instead of printing multiple if statements. I appreciate everyone's help!

```
public void grades(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many grades would you like to enter? "); //user input how many grades user would like to enter
    int q = in.nextInt();

    double[] grades = new double[q]; //initialized array
    double sum = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < q; counter++){ //user enters # of grades they requested to enter
        System.out.println("Enter your grades: ");
        double grade = in.nextInt();
        grades[counter] = grade; //grade values stored in array
    }
    System.out.println("Bar chart of grades: "); //title of printed list
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++){ //loop scans grades. Iterate through the grades array with filled values
        if (grades[i] <= 9) { //if grades stored in array fall within range
            System.out.println("0-9: " + '*'); //print those grades on graph
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your array called `grades` is storing each individual grade.  You probably want to use it to store a count of the number of grades in each range instead.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I am new to Java so I'm not sure how to do this. Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that helps you;

```
grades() {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many grades would you like to enter? "); //user input how many grades user would like to enter
    int q = in.nextInt();

    double[] grades = new double[q]; //initialized array
    double sum = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < q; counter++){ //user enters # of grades they requested to enter
        System.out.println("Enter your grades: ");
        double grade = in.nextInt();
        grades[counter] = grade; //grade values stored in array
    }

    int minInterval = 0;
    int maxInterval = 9;
    // you should loop for each interval
    while (maxInterval < 100) {
        System.out.print(minInterval + "-" + maxInterval + ":"); //print those grades on graph
        // print one asteriks for each grade falls in range
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++){ //loop scans grades. Iterate through the grades array with filled values
            if (minInterval <= grades[i] && grades[i] <= maxInterval ) { //if grades stored in array fall within range
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        minInterval += 9;
        maxInterval += 9;
    }

}
```

Comment: The range that is outputted is incorrect though. What changes to the max value or min value have to be made to make it so the outputted range is 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, 30-39, 40-49, 50-59, 60-69, 70-79, 80-89, 90-99, 100

Comment: Doing minInterval += 10, maxInterval += 10 can help you.